# extract all the substrings of a given length starting from each nucleotide position from a nucleotide sequence

Tags: perl

How to read a DNA sequence from a fasta File in Perl language and store it in an array and extract all the substrings of a given length starting from each nucleotide position?
I mean that I want to read a sequence which is very large 
and then split it to many sequences starting in each nucleotide position
that means the first sequence starts from the first nucleotide to the seventy
then the second sequence starts from the second nucleotide to the seventy-one and so on

Comment: Please provide some example, what exactly are you looking for, and also show some piece of code, what have tried so far?

Comment: What is a fasta file? I don't think there are too many users on SO who work with nucleotides and DNA sequences. There are however, a lot of perl hackers who *will* be able to answer your question if you provide more information that does not require one to learn about DNA/nucleotides and 'fasta' (whatever that means).

Comment: Have you searched [CPAN for bioperl](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=bioperl&mode=all)?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Bio::SeqIO](http://search.cpan.org/~cjfields/BioPerl-1.6.901/BioPerl.pm) from the bundled distribution of Bioperl, I came up with an example (if this is what you're after).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Bio::SeqIO;

my $in  = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file   => "fasta.txt",
                          -format => 'Fasta');

while ( my $seq = $in->next_seq() ) {
    print "Sequence ", $seq->id, "\n";
    for my $i (1 .. length($seq->seq) - 10) {
        print $seq->subseq($i,$i+10), "\n";
    }
}


__END__
*** Contents of fasta.txt

>chr1
AACCCCCCCCTCCCCCCGCTTCTGGCCACAGCACTTAAACACATCTCTGC
CAAACCCCAAAAACAAAGAACCCTAACACCAGCCTAACCAGATTTCAAAT
TTTATCTTTAGGCGGTATGCACTTTTAACAAAAAANNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
GCCCATCCTACCCAGCACACACACACCGCTGCTAACCCCATACCCCGAAC
CAACCAAACCCCAAAGACACCCCCCACAGTTTATGTAGCTTACCTCNNNN
>chrM
GATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTCTCCATGCAT
TTGGTATTTTCGTCTGGGGGGTGTGCACGCGATAGCATTGCGAGACGCTG
GAGCCGGAGCACCCTATGTCGCAGTATCTGTCTTTGATTCCTGCCTCATT
CTATTATTTATCGCACCTACGTTCAATATTACAGGCGAACATACCTACTA
AAGTGTGTTAATTAATTAATGCTTGTAGGACATAATAATAACAATTGAAT
GTCTGCACAGCCGCTTTCCACACAGACATCATAACAAAANAATTTCCACC
```